# checkbox that checks only one row in a checkboxes table jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, loops, checkbox

It seems that it's not a big deal but i still can't firgure out the problem:
In my razor view I display many checkboxes organized in three columns, and I want to create a checkbox for every row that checks all the row (every 3 checkboxes), so here is what i did using jQuery:

```
   <table>
        <tr>
            @{
                int cnt = 0;
                string sr =null;
                string j = null;
                List<Security.Models.AssignedRolesVM> Roles = ViewBag.tp_role;

                foreach (var role in Roles)
                {
                    if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                    { sr=cnt.ToString();
                      j =(cnt+1).ToString();
                     @:</tr><tr>
                         @: <td><input type="checkbox" id=j  /></td>
                            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
                            </script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function () {
                                    $(j).click(function () {
                                        $('input[name=sr]').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
                                    });
                                    $('input[name=sr]').click(function () {
                                        if ($('input[name=sr]').length == $('input[name=sr]:checked').length) {
                                            $(j).prop("checked", "checked");
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            $(j).removeProp("checked");
                                        }

                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
                    }
                    @:<td>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                           name=sr
                           class="checked"
                           value="@role.RoleID"
                           @(Html.Raw(role.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                           @role.RoleID @:  @role.Name
                    @:</td>
                }
                @:</tr>
            }
    </table>
```

but instead of checking only the row, it does check all the checkboxes.
It seems to me that the loop is correct (sr should change every time it is a modulo 3) , any help?

Comment: Mix of HTML, C# and JavaScrpt - all that I like. Do you understand that you most probably include jQuery and your script **multiple** times? Actually as many times, as there are `<tr>`s in `<table>`

Comment: Don't create all your JavaScript inline, create a reusable function that can be put into a .js file and thus cached and use "class" to control the behaviour of the controls. The example above isn't very readable or efficient.

Comment: @JeffWatkins well, it's not readable at all. What is really interesting for me: do people like their code?

Comment: okey i'll remove the script from the loop. but what about my question? input[name=sr] should refer to every three checkboxes with the same name, since it changes every time cnt%3=0 .

Comment: @Hasna766 most probably problem will disappear after you correctly redesign your code. Place scripts (jQuery link and your rewritten script placed in separate file) in `<head>` (or end of `<body>`), use HTML elements' attributes for keeping required information and be happy.

Comment: By the way, if after all script will still work not as you want to, you are welcome to post **rendered** HTML (what browser "sees", not mix of C# and HTML) and your JS code (which will be without any C# includes). Then it will be quite easy to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I recommend you separate the javascript away from being inline with the table like people have mentioned already.  It would then be easier to loop through the table and inject HTML after the table has been initialised.  Imagine if you had to update the table like in your example, seems like a right pain. http://api.jquery.com/after/